# Optimizing brute force algorithm

Tags: python, optimization, brute-force

I am currently in the midst of creating a brute-force algorithm and was wondering if there was a way I could optimize my program to run faster and take less time to generate all possible combinations.

```
import time

# 10.598227977752686 Seconds for 2 characters
# 488.21563148498535 Seconds for 3 characters

start = time.time()

chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' + 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' + '1234567890'

for char1 in chars:

    for char2 in chars:

        for char3 in chars:

            print(char1 + char2 + char3)

end = time.time()

print(end - start)
```

Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: @Zinki: it would be `itertools.product`

Comment: the time you're passing in your module is because of the print function. Removing it makes it run in less than 0.1 second with 3 characters.

Comment: As pointed out by @Jean-FrançoisFabre, most of the time is spent in your print. So the answer to your question depends on what you are doing with the data. You may often factorize some calculus (like char1 + char2)

Answer (score 3):

your bench is moot because most of the time is passed in `print` statement & console operations.

That said, you could simplify your code using `itertools.product` and `string` module:

```
import itertools,string

chars = string.ascii_letters+string.digits
for t in itertools.product(chars,repeat=3):
    c = "".join(t)
    # do whatever you want with c string
```

but it doesn't run much faster on my end with a 3-length string.

It's beginning to become interesting with a 4-length string, where 4 nested python loops take 4 seconds on my machine, whereas `itertools.product(chars,repeat=4)` take only 3 seconds.

This is explained because `itertools.product` uses native code on mainstream platforms, which is much faster than classic python loops (also `c = "".join(t)` is faster than char-by-char concatenation if the length is large enough)

Answer (score 1):

you could use some `itertools` power:

```
from itertools import product
list(product(chars, chars, chars))
```

that when timing it takes:

```
28.2 ms ± 1.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```